# Prove $A \cap(\cup B) = \cup\{(A \cap C)\mid C \in B\}$ using ZF

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My professor defined the union as the following:
$$\cup C:=\{x\mid\exists A\in C,\,x\in A\}.$$
Now, let $x \in \cup\{(A \cap C)\mid C \in B\}$. Then,

\begin{align}
x \in \cup\{(A \cap C)\mid C \in B\}&\iff x\in U, \text{ for some } U\in A\cap C \\
&\iff U\in A, U\in C, x\in U, C\in B\\
&\implies x\in A, x\in C,C\in B&\\
&\iff x\in A, x\in\cup B\\
&\iff x \in A \cap(\cup B)
\end{align}

Thus, $\cup\{(A \cap C)\mid C \in B\}\subseteq A \cap(\cup B)$. Is this proof correct? If so, how do I assure that there exists a set $U$ such that $U\in A\cap C$ so that I can get a chain of $\iff$?

Comment: You are misreading "range-builder" notation and union. $x\in \cup\{(A\cap B)|C\in B\}\iff \exists C\in B, x\in A\cap C$.